# why do components in my web overlap one another when the browser is resized?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can someone tell why my webpage's components are overlapped when the browser is resized? and How to fix it? I noticed that if I replace the aboutContainer and the bottomContainer with the two copies of the topContainer, the problem does not occur. So I only know that there is something wrong with the two containers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap Example 2</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <style type="text/css">
        .navbar-brand{
            font-size:1.7em;
        }

        #topContainer{
            background-image:url("image/background2.jpg");
            width:100%;
            background-size:cover;
            color:white;

        }

        .box{
            background-color:#F1F1F1;
            border:1px solid grey;
        }

        #topRow{
            margin-top:150px;
            text-align:center;
        }
        #topRow h1{
            font-size:350%;
        }

        .bold{
            font-weight:bold;
        }
        .marginTop{
            margin-top:30px;
        }
        .center{
            text-align:center;
        }
        .buttonBorder{
            border:1px solid #F8F8F8;
        }
        .title{
            margin-top:30px;
            font-size:350%;
        }
        .image-size{
            margin:20px;
            width:300px;
            height:250px;
        }
        #bottomContainer{
            background-color:#B19CE3;
            width:100%;

        }

        .logo{
            height:100px;   
        }

        #myModal{
            margin-top:100px;

        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" >
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="">The way of GO</a>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>              

                </button>

            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active" ><a href="#topContainer">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#aboutContainer">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#bottomContainer">Playing Go</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/Phammanhhiep">Donate</a></li>

                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Username</label>
                        <input type="email" placeholder="email..." class="form-control" 
                        name="username"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" placeholder="password..." class="form-control" 
                        name="password"></input>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit"class="btn btn-success">Log In</input>
                    </div>                          
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="container contentContainer" id="topContainer">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" id="topRow">
                <h1>So, what is GO?</h1>
                <p class="lead ">Go is an ancient Chinese board game, in fact it's so ancient there is no other board game in the world 
                that we have found evidence of existing before go.</p>
                <p class="bold marginTop">Interested? Subscribe now!</p>

                <form class="marginTop">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control"placeholder="your email..."></input>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg marginTop buttonBorder" type="submit">Subscribe</button>

                </form>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="container contentContainer" id="aboutContainer">
        <div class="row center">
            <h1 class="center title">Why GO is Awesome</h1>
            <p class="lead">Summary of Go's history and awesomeness</p>

        </div>
        <div class="row center">
            <div class="col-md-4 marginTop">
                <h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></span> History</h2>
                <p>Brief introduction about the app. Brief introduction about the app. Brief introduction about the app.
                Brief introduction about the app. Brief introduction about the app.</p> 
                <button class="btn btn-success marginTop" data-toggle="modal"
                data-target="#myModal">Sign Up</button>
                <img class="image-size" src="image/pic1.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 marginTop">
                <h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></span> How-to-play</h2>
                <p>Brief introduction about the app. Brief introduction about the app. Brief introduction about the app.
                Brief introduction about the app. Brief introduction about the app.</p>         
                <button class="btn btn-success marginTop" data-toggle="modal"
                data-target="#myModal">Sign Up</button>
                <img class="image-size"  src="image/pic2.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 marginTop">
                <h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></span> Books</h2>
                <p>Brief introduction about the app. Brief introduction about the app. Brief introduction about the app.
                Brief introduction about the app. Brief introduction about the app.</p> 
                <button class="btn btn-success marginTop" data-toggle="modal"
                data-target="#myModal">Sign Up</button>
                <img class="image-size" src="image/pic3.jpg" />
            </div>      
        </div>

        <div class="modal" id="myModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                    <h2 class="marginTop center">The way of GO</h2>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input  class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="your email"></input>

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="password"></input>

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input  class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="confirm password"></input>

                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign Up</button>      
                    </form>

                    </div>


                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="container contentContainer" id="bottomContainer">
        <div class="row center marginTop">
            <h1 class="center title">Playing GO now!</h1>
            <p class="lead center">Two most popular websites for go players</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row center marginTop">
            <div class="col-md-6 center" >
                <h1 class="title">KGS</h1>
                <img class="marginTop logo" src="image/kgslogo.png" /></br>
                <button class="btn btn-success marginTop">Play now!</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 center">
                <h1 class="title">Pandanet</h1>
                <img class="marginTop logo" src="image/pandanet.png" /></br>
                <button class="btn btn-success marginTop">Play now!</button>
            </div>      
        </div>

    </div>



    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(".contentContainer").css("height", $(window).height()+"px");

    </script>   

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: $(".contentContainer").css("height", "auto");

Answer (score 0):

It was because you were specifying the height of the containers.

http://plnkr.co/edit/lyDWUbFRJbHVVH0WYcyA

I commented out

```
<script>
    $(".contentContainer").css("height", $(window).height()+"px");
</script>
```

and it doesn't overlap anymore. Simply wrapping that code in a resize handler will not work. You might wanna use `margin`s or `padding`s instead. I haven't tested, though.

There were also quite a few other HTML errors that I fixed.